# Getting error while downloading Java

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java, sudo

I am trying to install Java in my AWS EC2 instance by using this below command:

```
sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
```

But I'm facing the below error:

```
No match for argument: java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64
Error: Unable to find a match: java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-34-139 newproject]$
```

Comment: Edit your question so it includes the output of “grep openjdk /etc/yum.conf”

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but a I sorted with solution provided on this link [Jenkins on AWS](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/tutorial-for-installing-jenkins-on-AWS/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).